# How to enable Eclipse (Mars) to search for slot calls?

Tags: eclipse, qt

Call Hierarchy option for a function (Ctrl+Alt+H) shows the direct calls to a function. If the function is a slot, is there a simple method to see where all this slot is "connected"?

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "slot call"?

Comment: Do you use `SLOT()` macro in connect statements? Try to use [new connect syntax](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax) and see if Hierarchy option works correctly.

Comment: try find references -> project or workspace

Comment: @PavelStrakhov unfortunately yes because of using QT 4.6.

Comment: By slot call I mean QT slot function connected using "connect"/

Comment: I think the only way to fix this is to find some Qt-specific plugin for the IDE.  Old-style Qt connect statements are not function calls, so code analyzers don't recognize them.